# WKWebView Cookie Sync Issue in iOS 17

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview, ios17, wkhttpcookiestore

I am facing a strange issue where in cookie sync fails(Few cookies drop) after upgrading to iOS 17 on some of the devices.

**How Cookie Sync works in Our App?**

- Authentication token is received via header in REST call.
- The tokens are synced with `NSHTTPCookieStorage` & `WKHTTPCookieStore`
- The WKWebView Request attaches the cookies found in WKHTTPCookieStore to the HTTP request.

**What's the Issue?**

WKWebView misses attaching few of the cookies randomly on iOS 17 on few of the devices.

**How widespread is the issue?**

1. It was reported by 3 people in our organisation.
2. This issue has been reported by 8-10 end users.
3. This issue was reproducible on one of the iPhone 14 pro devices.

**Did any fix work?**

Resetting the iOS device settings to default worked for few of the end users, but failed to work on the device where the bug is still reproducible.

**What We Tried?**

- We tried setting the Cookies Manually to `NSMutableRequest` in `WKWebView` post disabling Cookie auto sync via `setHTTPShouldHandleCookies`. It worked in all the cases except when the app is logged out and logged in again without going to foreground.

Please help with plausible solutions.